# How can I filter Google Analytics to view data related to subdomains/pages?

Tags: google-analytics, domains, subdomain

I have a website at the URL `www.example.com`, and I have another page at the URL `hello.example.com/cornerstone` which uses the same tracking ID. In my default analytics view I can only view data related to `www.example.com`, even though I tried creating a segment and filter by page/page title still I don't get to see the data of my subdomain.

Can someone explain me how to filter data by URL and view data related to all the subdomains/pages which uses the same tracking ID? (I don't want to use another property for the subdomain.)

Comment: Sharing a property between subdomains is perfectly fine, so I'm sure this can be worked out. I have a few clarifying questions: Do you mean the Behavior > Site Content > All Pages report has nothing beginning with `/cornerstone`? Are you using Google Tag Manager, or plain GA? Is there a possibility that a View Filter is restricting hits to the www domain only?

Comment: Agree with @Reve. Based on information what you provided, it looks like you're applying hostname based filter on the view level or you have issues with a tracking code on your subdomain. Test 1: Do you see any Real Time data in your GA if you clicking on your subdomain website? Test 2: Do you see your subdomain here: Audience -> Technology -> Network and switching Primary Dimension to Hostname? In any of these two test the answer is negative, your tracking is with issues or you have filter which is based on hostname.